# Visual Studio Community 2015 displays a tool box during the execution of the app

Tags: visual-studio

When I launch my app with Visual Studio, a black tools box appears at the top of the screen, hiding the middle of my own tools bar.

[image: http://hpics.li/6d82fdf]

How can I get rid of it ?

Comment: Have you some add-in or third party tool installed in Visual Studio?

Comment: You're right Martheen. I didn't know how to name this box, so I hadn't found this answer. Thanks !